# More than one selector for context menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I have two different context menus against different elements? I tried this but though I don't get errors, it doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.dragIndiv, .dragGroup', 
    autoHide: 'true',
    callback: function(key, options) {
      // do something
    },
    items: {
      "amend"   : {name: "Amend", icon: "amend"},
      "relate"  : {name: "Relate", icon: "relate"}
    },
    selector: '#elementPallet', 
    autoHide: 'true',
    callback: function(key, options) {
      // do something else
    },
    items: {
      "submit" : {name: "Submit", icon: "aligntop"},
      "viewSource": {name: "View source", icon: "alignleft"},
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html), I think you can only specified one `items` option per context menu. So can't you just create two context menus then?

```js
$(function(){
  // first context menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.dragIndiv, .dragGroup', 
    autoHide: 'true',
    callback: function(key, options) {
      // do something
    },
    items: {
      "amend"   : {name: "Amend", icon: "amend"},
      "relate"  : {name: "Relate", icon: "relate"}
    }
  });
  
  // second context menu
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '#elementPallet', 
    autoHide: 'true',
    callback: function(key, options) {
      // do something else
    },
    items: {
      "submit" : {name: "Submit", icon: "aligntop"},
      "viewSource": {name: "View source", icon: "alignleft"},
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/1.6.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/1.6.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="dragIndiv">Individual</div>
  <div class="dragGroup">Group</div>
  <div id="elementPallet">Pallet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this isim but only the first one works for me. I will try to see why and revert.

Comment: Any error message in your browser debugger console?

Comment: Only the same 3 "Unknown property" errors that occur with my snippet below. I will fix them anyway and revert.

Comment: I found the problem @isim, element pallet is hidden, I meant widget pallet. It's now working, using the correct div<>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my more complex context menu that is working here (using isim's solution) but doesn't work in my live environment (the second menu is ignored):-

```js
    $(function(){
      // first context menu
      $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.dragIndiv, .dragGroup', 
        autoHide: 'true',
        callback: function(key, options) {
          // do something
        },
        items: {
          "amend"    : {name: "Amend", icon: "amend"},
          "relate"   : {name: "Relate", icon: "relate"},
          "hide"     : {name: "Hide", icon: "hide"},
          "delete"   : {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
          "sep1"     : "---------",
          "submenu1" : {name: "Align",
            items: {
              "aligntop" : {name: "Top", icon: "aligntop"},
              "alignleft": {name: "Left", icon: "alignleft"},
              "alignbtm" : {name: "Bottom", icon: "alignbtm"},
              "alignrght": {name: "Right", icon: "alignrght"}
            }
          },
          "sep2"     : "---------",
          "submenu2" : {name: "Grid",
            items: {
              "gridon"   : {name: "Grid on", icon: "gridon"},
              "gridoff"  : {name: "Grid off", icon: "gridoff"},
              "gridshow" : {name: "Grid show", icon: "gridshow"},
              "gridhide" : {name: "Grid hide", icon: "gridhide"}
            }
          }
        }
      });

      // second context menu
      $.contextMenu({
        selector: '#elementPallet', 
        autoHide: 'true',
        callback: function(key, options) {
          // do something else
        },
        items: {
          "submit"     : {name: "Submit", icon: "submit"},
          "viewSource" : {name: "View source", icon: "viewsource"},
          "runQuery"   : {name: "Run query", icon: "runquery"},
          "manage"     : {name: "Manage tables", icon: "mtables"}
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
    div{
      margin:5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/1.6.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/1.6.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div>
      <div class="dragIndiv">Individual</div>
      <div class="dragGroup">Group</div>
      <div id="elementPallet">Pallet</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I changed the code snippet to use my live stylesheet in case that was causing the problem but the code is still working here but not in my live environment.